# What does 学位 mean in this context?

Tags: translation, culture

合X县、鹿X县、北X市等8个县义务教育学位均出现了严重短缺，其中，北X市小学位缺口达到XXXXX人，目前在建城区小学4所，预计新增学位XXXX个

I know that 学位 is a degree for a college graduate but do not know it is now even available to boys and girls of elementary schools. So it might be something new which I have yet to know. What does it really mean?

Answer (score 1):

That was literally a WRONG usage of the word there. "学位" is the proper noun for academic degree, there's no 2nd meaning in proper Chinese.

It should be “名额”，means quota. Or, to be more specifically, “入学名额” or “招生名额”。

So, in a normal way of speaking, that should be:

合X县、鹿X县、北X市等8个县义务教育**招生名额**均出现了严重短缺，其中，北X市小**名额**缺口达到XXXXX人，目前在建城区小学4所，预计新增**名额**XXXX个

However, this is a perfect evidence that proofs my conclusion:

**中文已经成了意识流。**

Chinese has become a stream of consciousness or even subconsciousness now days. There's no right or wrong, correct or mistake, but all about context, and who said so. It is no longer a communication tool with accuracy anymore (or, maybe never was?).

By "who said so" means, as long as a mistake is made by "higher level" or "authority", people will find all kinds of ways to explain how correct and how good that was.

Comment: quote: "中文已经成了意识流" I am with you on this part, I would like to say 素質 is wrong when you meant to say 質數; 員警 is wrong when it should be 警員. when too many people use a "wrong word" the wrong word eventually becomes acceptable and understandable.

Comment: @TangHo Thanks for your support.

Comment: The usage of 学位 to mean "quota" appears to have become standard, so is no longer "wrong". 《现代汉语词典》第7版 p. 1489: 【学位】1. 根据专业学术水平由高等院校、科研机构等授予的称号，如博士、硕士、学士等。(Academic degree) 2. 指入学名额。(Student quota)

Answer (score 0):

It is not that [学位](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%AD%A6%E4%BD%8D/234537)

**学位** here is an unofficial shorthand for "**学**生席**位**" (available student seats) **in this context** (what the writer wanted to express).

More specifically, "可供学生入学的席位" (available seats for students to enroll)

When there are more children applying to enroll than the school can accept, we have a 学位 (available student seats) shortage

To increase available student seats, the school needs to add more classrooms and teachers

**Edit:**

comment:

> No. That was literally a wrong word there.

It is not an actual word but a shorthand here, I just explained what the writer meant by saying so.

Comment: Languages are ever evolving. I am a native Chinese speaker. This is the first time I ever heard 学位 is used this way. I learn a lesson today. Thanks.

Comment: when you see  the term "学位" associated with  words like 充足，短缺，增加， or 減少， you know we are not talking about the other "学位" (an academic title)

Comment: 学额 may be a more familiar term to you, which is short for "学生名额 "

Comment: I am in Taiwan. "学生名额" is crystal clear to me. and used here.  "学额" is not common here. I think "学位" and "学额" are being used because of less typing when using computer.

Comment: It is taken out of a survey report of a local researcher. Could it be a place? 位置？A place for accomodating a student?

Comment: 位置 is ok. It has to be translated as "spots" instead of "place"

Comment: @Nobody Mainland Chinese like to do it in real-life conversation, for example,  I heard someone say 郎教 instead of 郎(平)教練; 張隊 instead of 張隊長; 陳總 instead of 陳總裁

Comment: No. That was literally a wrong word there. Trying to explain why something wrong is correct, is a mistake.

Comment: @Weishan Yang
 I didn't say it is a word, It is an unofficial "shorthand', just like 郎教, and 張隊 were not actually terms but shorthands. I just explained what 学位 means in this context, and many people do use this term the way I stated,

Comment: A sports coach is called X指导 but not X 教练, if you often watch live games on TV in China, something like X 医生 is not the right form of address but X 大夫 is.

Comment: @NanningYouth I believe "郎教頭" or "郎頭" are more widely known/used for "郎平".

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the 1-child policy??

合X县、鹿X县、北X市等8个县义务教育学位均出现了严重短缺，
With 莫county，Lu莫county, North 莫 city etc. 8 counties (are) all showing serious shortages in compulsory education student places,
其中，北X市小学位缺口达到XXXXX人，
among which, in North 莫 city the shortfall of primary education places reaches 5 figures,
目前在建城区小学4所，
(and) at the moment (they are) building 4 primary schools within the city,
预计新增学位XXXX个
(which, it is) estimated, will create thousands of new primary education places.

As Tang Ho says, in the context, it is not academic qualifications that are in short supply!

Comment: OK, it is clear, what you say makes much sense. But the problem is not due to the one-child policy, to the contrary, it is a problem of multiple-children policy in my opinion. A problem of supply and demand, LOL.

Comment: That was literally a wrong expression. "学位" means academic degree, there's no 2nd meaning in proper Chinese. Trying to explain why something literally wrong been correct, is a mistake. See my answer.

Comment: Chinese speakers and writers always leave out words, because everyone knows what is meant. This can make Chinese very hard to understand for non-Chinese!

Comment: The problem to me is that the OP seems to be in an official document. This non-standard usage of "学位" should not appear there unless somebody invented this usage long time ago which the asker did not know. As a native speaker, I did not know this either until I saw this question.

Comment: Haha, recently there was a question with 知感，not 感知！Language belongs to the people! They may use it as they wish!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the author meant "**學**生座**位**" but wrongfully abbreviated as "**學位**".